# Creating custom bread crumb trails (Drupal 7)

Tags: 7, breadcrumbs

How would one create a custom breadcrumb such as this:

[image]

For a given page such as a node or organic group page in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know anything about Organic Groups, otherwise I'm using [Path breadcrumbs](http://drupal.org/project/path_breadcrumbs) and [Custom Breadcrumbs](http://drupal.org/project/custom_breadcrumbs).

Comment: I was having trouble with Custom Breadcrumbs but I found one called Hansel that ended up working well.